# REST API for getting performance metrics for an HDInsight cluster?

Tags: rest, azure-api-management, azure-hdinsight, azure-rest-api

I am looking for REST API that will allow me to fetch performance metrics for a given HDInsight (Hadoop/Linux) cluster -- such as amount or percentage of memory used by the cluster, cpu usage etc. But I haven't come across anything specific. The only closest link I have found is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-manage-ambari-rest-api). But this too doesn't have any reference to getting performance metrics. Is this info even exposed as REST API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to get the metrics of the cluster. If so, you can use the following rest api to get it. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Ambari+Metrics+API+specification) and [article](https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/docs/api/v1/index.md)

```
Method: GET
URL: https://<clustername>.azurehdinsight.net//api/v1/clusters/<cluster-name>?fields=metrics/load[<start time>,<end time>,<step>]

Headers : Authorization: Basic <username password>
```

For example:

Get CPU usage
[image]

Comment: @dhiraj Is it useful for you?